# Distributed training using Keras model and tf.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Following the example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators#creating_estimators_from_keras_models) one can create a `tf.Estimator` from an existing `keras` model. In the beginning this page states that by doing so, one can use benefits of the `tf.Estimator` such as an increased training speed due to distributed training. Sadly, when I run the code only one of the GPUs in my system is used for computations; therefore, there is no increase of speed. How exactly can I use distributed learning with an estimator built from a `keras` model?

I stumbpled upon this method:

```
distributed_model = tf.keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)
```

which sounds like it would take care of this problem. But this is not working at the moment, as it creates a graph which uses the `get_slice(..)` method defined in `tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/utils/training_utils.py` and this method fails with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "hub.py", line 75, in <module>
    estimator = create_model_estimator()   File "hub.py", line 67, in create_model_estimator
    estimator = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=new_model, custom_objects={'tf': tf}, model_dir=model_dir, config=run_config)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py", line 302, in model_to_estimator
    _save_first_checkpoint(keras_model, est, custom_objects, keras_weights)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py", line 231, in _save_first_checkpoint
    custom_objects)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/estimator.py", line 109, in _clone_and_build_model
    model = models.clone_model(keras_model, input_tensors=input_tensors)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 1557, in clone_model
    return _clone_functional_model(model, input_tensors=input_tensors)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/models.py", line 1451, in _clone_functional_model
    output_tensors = topology._to_list(layer(computed_tensor, **kwargs))   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 258, in __call__
    output = super(Layer, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/layers/base.py", line 696, in __call__
    outputs = self.call(inputs, *args, **kwargs)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/layers/core.py", line 630, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)   File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/utils/training_utils.py", line 156, in get_slice
    shape = array_ops.shape(data) NameError: name 'array_ops' is not defined
```

So, what can I do to use both of my GPUs to train a model with a `tf.Estimator` object?

**Edit**: By switching the version/build of `tensorflow` I was able to get rid of the previous error message, but now I get this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1312, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1420, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 516, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value res2a_branch2c/bias
         [[Node: res2a_branch2c/bias/_482 = _Send[T=DT_FLOAT, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1142_res2a_branch2c/bias", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](res2a_branch2c/bias)]]
         [[Node: bn4a_branch2a/beta/_219 = _Recv[_start_time=0, client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_878_bn4a_branch2a/beta", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Maybe this is connected to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18193)?

Answer (score 0):

you should setting distributed running config.

you can reference this demo for tensorflow high level API(estimator) for distributed training.

https://github.com/colinwke/wide_deep_demo